# Find html node in react component for initialization after component mounts. Instance from JSX.Element creation

Tags: reactjs, initialization, materialize

I initialize the materialize dropdowns in my component like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    selects.forEach(select => {
      M.FormSelect.init(select, {
        dropdownOptions: {
          //...options not relevant
        }
      });
    });
    // console.log('select count: ', selects.length);
  }
```

That works fine, as long as all the dropdowns of my component are part of the component itself, meaning that there is no dropdown conditionally rendered. If there is, the dropdown is not initialized, hence, does not work.

Not working case:

```
render() {
    let conditionalComponent:JSX.Element = <></>;
    if (this.state.projectTypeSelected === '1') {
      conditionalComponent = 
      <div className="input-field col s3">
        <MaterializeDropdown options={['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']} placeholderText='number of hits'/>
      </div>;
      //NEED DROPDOWN POST INITIALIZATION HERE
    }
    return(
    //...not relevant JSX elements
    {conditionalComponent}
    )
}
```

Because the fact of the conditional render, the dropdown is not initialized, because its not found by the `document.querySelectorAll('select')` when the component mounts. Checked with `// console.log('select count: ', selects.length);`

So I tried to post initialize in `//NEED DROPDOWN POST INITIALIZATION HERE` (check code above) the dropDown with:

```
const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(conditionalComponent);
```

But get the error: `Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactInstance | null | undefined'.`. Makes sense, as there seem to be no instance of the react element.

So I tried to create it:

`const element = React.createElement(conditionalComponent);`

But get the error: `No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error. Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | FunctionComponent<{}> | ComponentClass<{}, any>'.`

I think I would need to create the react element intance from the JSX.Element, so that then I can find the `html` select element with a `htmlnode.querySelector('select')` to make an initialization as in the `ComponentDidMount()`. I had a look to the element, component, instance difference [documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#:%7E:text=In%20React%2C%20this%20is%20where%20the%20elements%20come,it.%20An%20element%20is%20not%20an%20actual%20instance.) but I am not able to achieve this and I am not sure if this is the way to go. Does this instance creation from JSX.Element for initialization idea make any sense or is there any other approach for my problem?

I tried to make my question as clear as possible, but I will provide a codesandbox with the isolated full component upon request if there is interest in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a bug in your code. And react wrote about it.
Try using React fragment when returning value from render method.

```
render() {
    let conditionalComponent:JSX.Element = <></>;
    if (this.state.projectTypeSelected === '1') {
      conditionalComponent = 
      <div className="input-field col s3">
        <MaterializeDropdown options={['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']} placeholderText='number of hits'/>
      </div>;
      //NEED DROPDOWN POST INITIALIZATION HERE
    }
    return(
      <>
        {conditionalComponent}
      </>
    )
}
```